# #2002 - lampp phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, lampp

I have mysql running on another as another installation.
I downloaded xampp and installed it, and it is running. I have this error #2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed when I try to run phpmyadmin I have two installation of mysql considering i had one with socket set to
/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock and another at /opt/lampp/etc/mysql/mysql.sock(xampp).
I need to make phpmyadmin use this socket /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

If you are using windows then you can try by following this steps:

1. Go to C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini (default installation location, change to suit) in your text editor
2. Find out "bind-address" and then uncomment this line (remove this character # from the beginning of the line) so that it looks like

   > bind-address = "127.0.0.1"
3. Save the file and restart Apache and MySQL.